# Can I redirect questions to Ubuntu forums when needed?

Tags: discussion

I understand that AU is for questions about *how to* use ubuntu software and that is conflicting me regarding questions that are about support or fixing something that the users can't solve and needing a fresh eye on the problem.

I find better-suited to use Ubuntu Forums for those questions since support or a fresh eye takes discussion of the question in hand and because it is designed mainly for this.

This is the concept I have about how to. **Clarification of the documentation in steps or maybe something missing**. This like which menu has the option that the user is looking for or that *new feature* that landed on my application. This are *how to* instead of *errors* where the OP would need clarifications and seems to belong to a platform like a forum.

The reason here is **not that giving support is inadequate but pursuing a better UX** with a more suited platform. I'm thinking about the experience the users are getting from using the *Ask Ubuntu UI* for support which is not **threaded as the Ubuntu Forums**.

This are the examples:

- The user might have encountered something that still has not being developed in this case, how can a *how to* then exist?
- The user has encountered a Bug, Then there is not a *how to* since there's a bug.
- There's a workaround for a bug, That's not a *how to* it is indeeed a *workaround*

Maybe we could advise the information gathering before moving to the forums, what do you guys think?

- Resolve here at AU
- Information gathering and forums redirect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I need to clarify something - I think you're creating an issue where none exists; either that or it's supremely unclear what you're ultimately asking (and why I'm closing the question).  In the thousands of things I've reviewed and the many many flags I've reviewed (and burned through as needed), the only time we've sent someone to the forums was... what, never?  Except to refer to the 'source' of a fix, which usually ends up as a comment or such, unless the details are extracted and added to the answer.

You need to provide ***solid examples*** when proposing a "fix" and such - cases where this is an issue, or cases where something like this would be needed - not ***vague examples***.  Using your examples below, though, I'm going to critique:

> This are the examples:
>
> - The user might have encountered something that still has not being developed in this case, how can a how to then exist?

Core problem: User may not know it's still not developed.  Therefore we can't document it, or provide clear assistance, and we reply that "It's still in development and not available, details can be tracked at [upstream tracker location]."  Same as we've always done.

Sending users to the forums doesn't help - it's the same "answer" in both places - "This isn't developed yet"

> - The user has encountered a Bug, Then there is not a how to since there's a bug.

We don't send them to the forums - we close their item as a "bug report" link to the "How do I report a bug" canonical item and the Bug Squad wiki data, and then that's it.  No redirection to the forums needed.

Forums will ultimately do the same exact thing - they'll look at it, determine it's a bug, suggest a bug be filed, and maybe find a workaround.  That's not much different than here, so why force users to register elsewhere just to get a 'second look' that we already give here?

> - There's a workaround for a bug, That's not a how to it is indeeed a workaround

Answer that "This is currently a bug, and can be tracked here: [bug tracker link].  There is a proposed workaround, however:  [details]".

Again, you'd see the same core issue at the forums.  That hasn't changed.

> Maybe we could advise the information gathering before moving to the forums, what do you guys think?
>
> ```
> * Resolve here at AU
> * Information gathering and forums redirect
> ```

Read my above points.  I don't think sending people to the forums is the best idea, because we'll not only be doubling the workload of the user posting (because they now have to register and repost at a separate site), but we're doubling the workload of the community by having to refer to two separate locations and have two separate teams moderating the content.  And in your three examples above, the core solution is the same on *each* of the sites.

If it can't be resolved on AU because it's a bug or it's not developed, it's not going to get resolved on the forums.  If there's a workaround, state it here, that's what'd happen on the forums too.  There's ***very few cases*** where we'd need to forward something out to the forums, and none of them are the example cases you've proposed.

Comment: You're right I brought a problem and not a solution